# Windows 8 RT - Dynamically generating html does not render images

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am unable to get images loaded on a webpage when in the LocalState directory.

Specifically, there appears to be a security issue when attempting to launch the webpage when the file path is referencing the LocalState directory.

The webpage DOES load with images when I right-click the html file and view it in the browser within Visual Studio.

I have changed the path of the src tag to: src="ms-appdata:///Local/Logo.jpeg"
It doesn't work.

Help me...

Example code

```
public static async Task Update(WebView webview, IStorageFile file) { 
  var html = await Windows.Storage.PathIO.ReadTextAsync(file.Path);
  webview.NavigateToString(html);
 }
```

Comment: Are you loading the HTML file into a WebView element?

Comment: Are you using the WebView.Navigate or WebView.NavigateTo methods to load the HTML page?

Comment: public static async Task Update(WebView webview, IStorageFile file)
{
   var html = await Windows.Storage.PathIO.ReadTextAsync(file.Path);
   webview.NavigateToString(html);
}

Comment: I am using NavigateToString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NavigateToString method doesn't work with  tags that point to images in the LocalData folder. (as far as I recall anyway).  In fact NavigateToString also breaks JavaScript and CSS links.

**Images on Server**

One solution, is to change your  source to point to a network server instead of localdata.  I'm not sure it that works for your app scenario though.

**Images and HTML as content**

The second choice is to add your html and image files as content to your app and use

```
WebView1.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///assets/SampleHtmlPage.html"));
```

to load the HTML.

**In Process HTTP Server**

Here is a solution that uses a custom HTTP server in the app to handle the issues.

[Loading Local HTML Content in Metro WebView (Windows 8)](http://blog.jsolutions.co.uk/?p=492)

**Base 64 encoded image**

Finally, there is another solution using Base64 encoding of your images in the LocalData folder.

```
internal async void MakeHtmlString()
{
  StorageFile imageFile; // get image file here.

  var html = 
     string.Format("<div><img src='data:image/png;base64,{0}'", 
                    await GetImageBase64(imageFile));
}

internal async Task<string> GetImageBase64(StorageFile imageFile)
{
  var imageStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
  var inputStream = imageStream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
  var dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream);

  var dataResults = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)imageStream.Size);
  var bytes = new byte[dataResults];
  dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

This last approach works for images, but not for CSS files.

Comment: Here is a thread on MSDN forums that discusses some possibilities. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/cbde9333-ba45-4b62-84f7-9f4c38ecbeb1